# 2 subclass of Canvas on single Shell

Tags: java, canvas, swt, subclass, paint

I want to build a maze with player that move on the maze board.
I create 2 subclasses `Canvas`: the first to draw the maze and the secend to draw the player.
In every subclass of `Canvas` I override the method of `Paint` so basicly it looks like this:

```
public class MazeCanvas extends Canvas {

// override 
public void paint(Graphics win) {
} 

 } 

public class PlayerCanvas extends Canvas {

// override 
public void paint(Graphics win) {
} 

 } 

public class ShellClass implements ActionListener {
public void run() {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.open();
            Button goButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
            goButton.addActionListener(shell);
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == goButton) {
        //here I want to repaint the obj of PlayerCanvas  ; 
    }
    }
```

So .. my question is:
what do I have to do in order that the 2 subclasses of `Canvas` will be set on the `Shell` in class `ShellClass`?
If I use basic `Canvas` I write :

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.MAX);
```

but what do I have to write if it's a subclass of `Canvas`?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subclassing `Canvas` or `Composite`, you should always include a constructor with 2 arguments, which calls the superclass constructor:

```
public class MazeCanvas extends Canvas {
    public MazeCanvas(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        ... // anything else you need to initialize your subclass
    }

    ...
}
```

And then you place your subclasses the same way you'd place any other controls.

Comment: I tried this but get error    'The constructor Canvas(Composite, int) is undefined'

Comment: @URL87 It is defined: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Canvas.html#Canvas(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite,%20int) And your question shows you can call this constructor. So I don't see how this error could appear.

Comment: I had  "import java.awt.Canvas" i changed it to "import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas" and now it work !! thanks !